# How do I solve PyAudio installation error?

Tags: python, windows, installation, pip, pyaudio

So, I was looking for some voice recognition project and I need to use the PyAudio lib, but, when installing it in Windows I just receive some erros of installation.

The method of installation that I'm using is:
`pip install pyaudio`

When I execute the command in cmd the result is:

```
   command: 'c:\users\pedro\virtualenvs\pyjarvis\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\pedro\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tbw4bc33\\pyaudio_3d715acd64eb45979bf989d5585f978d\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\pedro\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tbw4bc33\\pyaudio_3d715acd64eb45979bf989d5585f978d\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-9omziclx'
       cwd: C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tbw4bc33\pyaudio_3d715acd64eb45979bf989d5585f978d\
  Complete output (9 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyAudio
  Running setup.py clean for PyAudio
Failed to build PyAudio
Installing collected packages: PyAudio
    Running setup.py install for PyAudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\pedro\virtualenvs\pyjarvis\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\pedro\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tbw4bc33\\pyaudio_3d715acd64eb45979bf989d5585f978d\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\pedro\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-tbw4bc33\\pyaudio_3d715acd64eb45979bf989d5585f978d\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-mzmmtmwh\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\pedro\virtualenvs\pyjarvis\include\site\python3.9\PyAudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\pedro\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tbw4bc33\pyaudio_3d715acd64eb45979bf989d5585f978d\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

That's the problem, what should I do?

Comment: The error says it all *Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpyaudio%5D+error%3A+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+or+greater+is+required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though the error says *error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required*. You can try installing the unofficial python binary for pyaudio from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio).

Note - Install the wheel package in accordance of your system and python version.

For example if your system is of 64 bit and you running python 3.9.x then you will have to install `PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl`

After you're done with the installation open up your terminal and navigate to the folder where the wheel package is installed, then enter the following command

```
pip install your_wheel_package_name.whl
```